# ¿Cómo valido si una variable tiene valor?

Tags: c++

Bien, soy nuevo en esto de la programación, estoy en el primer semestre del mismo, me encuentro haciendo mi primer programa y proyecto del semestre. El caso es, voy bien. Pero tengo una duda. Al momento de imprimir parte del código por pantalla. Si la primera coordenada **"CORD_X_IZQ"** son un par de dígitos entra en una condicional. Hasta aquí bien, la cosa es, que al final del código(Por lo que llevo ahora) Coloco para que imprima la segunda parte del las coordenadas X.

*Ya que si son 4 dígitos estos se parten en 2 para hacer un par de números y dirigirse a una letra en específico*

Me encuentro en el dilema de que al momento de imprimir la segunda parte de las coordenadas *(Esta estando sin valor alguno, estando en NULL)* de todas maneras me imprimía un espacio.

PD: Para este punto, al escribir NULL realmente me di cuenta de lo que podía hacer por mi mismo, de igual manera el compilador me tira las siguientes advertencias:

> 460   20  C:\Users\RoderickJosue\Desktop\Programacion\Untitled1.cpp   [Warning] NULL used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
>
> 466   20  C:\Users\RoderickJosue\Desktop\Programacion\Untitled1.cpp   [Warning] NULL used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
>
> 472   20  C:\Users\RoderickJosue\Desktop\Programacion\Untitled1.cpp   [Warning] NULL used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
>
> 478   20  C:\Users\RoderickJosue\Desktop\Programacion\Untitled1.cpp   [Warning] NULL used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]

pero me interesan las sugerencias que puedan hacerme y aunque el programa funciona como quiero hasta ahora, quisiera saber si debería prestarle mucha atencion a esas advertencias. Siguiente a esta explicación adjunto el código. Tengan en cuenta que no se pueden usar arreglos, otras librerías que las que ya están, no se pueden usar bucles.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

        //Variables globales para poder guardar las X y Y de sus determinadas partes.
char X_IZQ_PART1, X_IZQ_PART2, Y_IZQ_PART1, Y_IZQ_PART2;

void Mostrar_Valor_Letra(char valor){
    printf("%c", valor);
}
            //Funcion para validar si hay un valor negativo
 int Validar_Negativo(int valor){
    if(valor <0){
        printf("NO VALIDO \n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

//Valida que el tamaño de los digitos sea igual a 4 como máximo.
int Validate_Size(int value){
    if(value >9999){
        printf("NO VALIDO\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

            //Funcion para validar las letras de las coordenadas en la izquierda
int Letras_Izquierda(int valor){
    switch(valor){
        char Numero_Izq;
        case 0:
        Numero_Izq = 'a';
        return Numero_Izq;
        break;

        case 1:
        Numero_Izq = 'b';
        return Numero_Izq;
        break;

        case 2:
        Numero_Izq = 'c';
        return Numero_Izq;
        break;

        case 3:
        Numero_Izq = 'd';
        return Numero_Izq;
        break;

        case 4:
        Numero_Izq = 'e';
        return Numero_Izq;
        break;

        case 5:
        Numero_Izq = 'f';
        return Numero_Izq;
        break;

        case 6:
        Numero_Izq = 'g';
        return Numero_Izq;
        break;

        case 7:
        Numero_Izq = 'h';
        return Numero_Izq;
        break;

        case 8:
        Numero_Izq = 'i';
        return Numero_Izq;
        break;

        case 9:
        Numero_Izq = 'j';
        return Numero_Izq;
        break;


                    case 10: 
                        Numero_Izq ='k';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 11:
                        Numero_Izq = 'l';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break; 

                    case 12:
                        Numero_Izq = 'm';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;  

                    case 13: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'n';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;  

                    case 14: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'o';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;  

                    case 15: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'p';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 16: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'q';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 17: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'r';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;  

                    case 18: 
                        Numero_Izq = 's';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;   

                    case 19: 
                        Numero_Izq = 't';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;  

                    case 20: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'u';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;       

                    case 21: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'v';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;  

                    case 22: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'w';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;      

                    case 23: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'x';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;  

                    case 24: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'y';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;  

                    case 25: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'z';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;  

                    case 26: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'A';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;  

                    case 27: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'B';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;  

                    case 28: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'C';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 29: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'D';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 30: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'E';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break; 

                    case 31: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'F';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 32: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'G';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 33: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'H';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 34: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'I';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 35: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'J';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 36: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'K';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 37: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'L';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 38: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'M';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 39: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'N';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 40: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'O';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 41: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'P';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 42: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'Q';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 43: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'R';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 44: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'S';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 45: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'T';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 46: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'U';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 47: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'V';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 48: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'W';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 49: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'X';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 50: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'Y';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;

                    case 51: 
                        Numero_Izq = 'Z';
                        return Numero_Izq;
                        break;
}
}

int Primer_Par(int valor){
        if(valor >= 1000){
        if(valor <= 9999){
            char PRIMER_PAR, SEGUNDO_PAR;
            PRIMER_PAR = valor/100;
            SEGUNDO_PAR = valor%100;
            return PRIMER_PAR;
        }
    }
}

int Segundo_Par(int valor){
        if(valor >= 1000){
        if(valor <= 9999){
            char PRIMER_PAR, SEGUNDO_PAR;
            PRIMER_PAR = valor/100;
            SEGUNDO_PAR = valor%100;
            return SEGUNDO_PAR;
        }
    }
}


int main(){

        //Coordenadas del meteoro
    int Mx1, My1, Mx2, My2; 
        //Coordenadas izquierda
    int CORD_X_IZQ, CORD_Y_IZQ;
        //Coordenadas derecha
    int CORD_X_DERE, CORD_Y_DERE;
        //coordenadas trayectoria
    int CORD_X_CENT, COD_Y_CENT;

        //Menú básico trayectoria del meteoro (Sin mucho más de lo que se pide)

    printf("Coordenada Mx1: ");
    scanf("%d", &Mx1);

            //Funciones de negativo y tamaño
        Validar_Negativo(Mx1);
        Validate_Size(Mx1);

    printf("Coordenada Mx2: ");
    scanf("%d", &Mx2);

        //Funciones de negativo y tamaño
        Validar_Negativo(Mx2);
        Validate_Size(Mx2);

    printf("Coordenada My1: ");
    scanf("%d", &My1);

        //Funciones de negativo y tamaño
        Validar_Negativo(My1);
        Validate_Size(My1);

    printf("Coordenada My2: ");
    scanf("%d", &My2);

    //Funciones de negativo y tamaño
        Validar_Negativo(My2);
        Validate_Size(My2);


    //Menú básico Coordenadas Izquierda (Sin mucho más de lo que se pide)

    printf("Coordenada X a la izquierda: ");
    scanf("%d", &CORD_X_IZQ);


    /*Declaracion de variable a la cual será guardada el retorno de la funcion Letras_Izquierda 
     + llamado de funciones para validar si hay negativo y el proceso de las letras a la izquierda */

        int VALOR_X_IZQ_PRIMER_PAR, VALOR_X_IZQ_SEGUNDO_PAR, MENOR_DIEZ, DOS_DIG;
        char VALOR_X_IZQ_PRIMER_PAR_LETRA, VALOR_X_IZQ_SEGUNDO_PAR_LETRA;       

    //Validacion de Negativo y Tamaño

        Validar_Negativo(CORD_X_IZQ);
        Validate_Size(CORD_X_IZQ);

    //Si el tamaño es menor a 4 Digitos

        if(CORD_X_IZQ <10){
            MENOR_DIEZ = Letras_Izquierda(CORD_X_IZQ);
            X_IZQ_PART1 = MENOR_DIEZ;
        }

    //Si el tamaño es igual a 2 digitos

        if(CORD_X_IZQ >=10){
            if(CORD_X_IZQ <=51){
                DOS_DIG = Letras_Izquierda(CORD_X_IZQ);
                X_IZQ_PART1 = DOS_DIG;
            }
        }

        //Si el tamaño es igual a 4 digitos

        if(CORD_X_IZQ >=1000){
            if(CORD_X_IZQ <=9999)

    //Se pica el numero en 2 si el mismo es de 4 cifras. Y se guardan los valores determinados por su función.

        VALOR_X_IZQ_PRIMER_PAR = Primer_Par(CORD_X_IZQ);
        VALOR_X_IZQ_SEGUNDO_PAR = Segundo_Par(CORD_X_IZQ);

    //Se agarran los pares, y se les asocia su debida letra segun lo determinado por su función.

        VALOR_X_IZQ_PRIMER_PAR_LETRA = Letras_Izquierda(VALOR_X_IZQ_PRIMER_PAR);
        VALOR_X_IZQ_SEGUNDO_PAR_LETRA = Letras_Izquierda(VALOR_X_IZQ_SEGUNDO_PAR);


        X_IZQ_PART1 = VALOR_X_IZQ_PRIMER_PAR_LETRA;
        X_IZQ_PART2 = VALOR_X_IZQ_SEGUNDO_PAR_LETRA;
        }

    printf("Coordenada Y a la izquierda: ");
    scanf("%d", &CORD_Y_IZQ);
        Validar_Negativo(CORD_Y_IZQ);

        //Declaración de Variables Necesarias.

        int VALOR_Y_IZQ_PRIMER_PAR, VALOR_Y_IZQ_SEGUNDO_PAR;
        char VALOR_Y_IZQ_PRIMER_PAR_LETRA, VALOR_Y_IZQ_SEGUNDO_PAR_LETRA;

    //Validacion de Negativo y Tamaño

        Validar_Negativo(CORD_Y_IZQ);
        Validate_Size(CORD_Y_IZQ);

    //Si el tamaño es menor a 4 Digitos
        if(CORD_Y_IZQ <10){
            MENOR_DIEZ = Letras_Izquierda(CORD_Y_IZQ);
            Y_IZQ_PART1 = MENOR_DIEZ;
        }
    //Si el tamaño es igual a 2 digitos
        if(CORD_Y_IZQ >=10){
            if(CORD_Y_IZQ <=51){
                DOS_DIG = Letras_Izquierda(CORD_Y_IZQ);
                Y_IZQ_PART1 = DOS_DIG;
            }
        }



    //Si el tamaño es igual a 4 digitos
        if(CORD_Y_IZQ >=1000){
            if(CORD_Y_IZQ <=9999)

    //Se pica el numero en 2 si el mismo es de 4 cifras. Y se guardan los valores determinados por su función.

        VALOR_Y_IZQ_PRIMER_PAR = Primer_Par(CORD_Y_IZQ);
        VALOR_Y_IZQ_SEGUNDO_PAR = Segundo_Par(CORD_Y_IZQ);

    //Se agarran los pares, y se les asocia su debida letra segun lo determinado por su función.

        VALOR_Y_IZQ_PRIMER_PAR_LETRA = Letras_Izquierda(VALOR_Y_IZQ_PRIMER_PAR);
        VALOR_Y_IZQ_SEGUNDO_PAR_LETRA = Letras_Izquierda(VALOR_Y_IZQ_SEGUNDO_PAR);


        Y_IZQ_PART1 = VALOR_Y_IZQ_PRIMER_PAR_LETRA;
        Y_IZQ_PART2 = VALOR_Y_IZQ_SEGUNDO_PAR_LETRA;
        }

    if(X_IZQ_PART1 == NULL){
        Mostrar_Valor_Letra(X_IZQ_PART2);
        Mostrar_Valor_Letra(Y_IZQ_PART1);
        Mostrar_Valor_Letra(Y_IZQ_PART2);
    }

    if(X_IZQ_PART2 == NULL){
        Mostrar_Valor_Letra(X_IZQ_PART1);
        Mostrar_Valor_Letra(Y_IZQ_PART1);
        Mostrar_Valor_Letra(Y_IZQ_PART2);
    }

    if(Y_IZQ_PART1 == NULL){
        Mostrar_Valor_Letra(X_IZQ_PART1);
        Mostrar_Valor_Letra(X_IZQ_PART2);
        Mostrar_Valor_Letra(Y_IZQ_PART2);
    }

    if(Y_IZQ_PART2 == NULL){
        Mostrar_Valor_Letra(X_IZQ_PART1);
        Mostrar_Valor_Letra(X_IZQ_PART2);
        Mostrar_Valor_Letra(Y_IZQ_PART1);
    }
    //  Mostrar_Valor_Letra(X_IZQ_PART2);

        printf("\n");




    return 0;
}
```

Estaría muy agradecido por sus respuestas(Si es que las hay) Sin mas, buenos días, tardes, noches. Y gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De las 491 líneas de tu código, son relevantes para la pregunta 2:

1. La declaración de las variables:

   ```
   char X_IZQ_PART1, X_IZQ_PART2, Y_IZQ_PART1, Y_IZQ_PART2;
   ```
2. Su uso:

   ```
   if(X_IZQ_PART1 == NULL){
   ```

Las variables `X_IZQ_PART1`, `X_IZQ_PART2`, `Y_IZQ_PART1`, y `Y_IZQ_PART2` son de tipo `char`, mientras que `NULL` es una macro que en general (dependiendo del compilador ys u versión) se define como un puntero `void` a la posición `0` o como `0` o como `nullptr`.

Por lo tanto estás comparando un tipo no puntero (`char`) con un puntero (`NULL`), de ahí que el compilador te diga que lo estás usando mal.

> ¿Cómo valido si una variable tiene valor?

Las variables siempre, SIEMPRE, **SIEMPRE** tienen valor, ya sea un valor asignado por el usuario, un valor asignado por el sistema o un valor residual, no puedes comprobar si una variable tiene o no tiene valor porque el concepto de *no tener valor* no existe.

Por tu código deduzco que lo que quieres es que algunos valores no sean tenidos en cuenta, dado que estás usando `char`, tienes 256 valores a elegir ¿qué te parece usar valores negativos para marcar los valores no válidos?

```
if (X_IZQ_PART1 < 0){
    // hacer cosas...
}

if(X_IZQ_PART2  < 0){
    // hacer cosas...
}

if(Y_IZQ_PART1  < 0){
    // hacer cosas...
}

if(Y_IZQ_PART2  < 0){
    // hacer cosas...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> quisiera saber si debería prestarle mucha atencion a esas advertencias

El compilador no muestra las advertencias por que le apetezca sacar mensajes por pantalla. Una advertencia sirve para indicar que, pese a que no se infringe ninguna regla explícita del lenguaje, esa parte del código puede ser problemática.

¿Cómo de problemática? Pues depende. Los warnings son bastante variados:

- Al convertir entre tipos se pueden perder decimales: 2/4=0 en vez de 0.5
- Al convertir entre tipos, el rango del tipo destino no es compatible con el tipo origen: posible error de desbordamiento
- Variables sin uso: Consumo innecesario de recursos
- Variables no inicializadas: Puedes acabar leyendo basura
- Uso de funciones obsoletas: el código no compilará en versiones más modernas del compilador
- Funciones sin return: el valor retornado es un misterio
- ...

Así pues tu programa podrá funcionar perfectamente aunque muestre warnings... o es posible que no, depende de muchos factores. Lo ideal sería que el programa compilase sin warnings ya que eso significará que el programa tiene menos puntos débiles.

> pero me interesan las sugerencias que puedan hacerme

**Etiqueta bien las preguntas**

C y C++ se parecen cada vez menos y cada uno tiene características que no existen en el otro lenguaje, así que no uses ambas etiquetas a la vez... o te riges por las reglas de C o por las de C++.

**Evita el uso de variables globales**

Conforme el programa crece es bastante complicado controlar qué funciones acceden a dichas variables. Las variables globales son la fuente de una gran cantidad de errores, así que yo de ti las evitaría en la medida de lo posible.

**Cuidado con los `switch`**

La instrucción `switch` es característica ya que, aunque tenga llaves... **no crea ámbitos**. Así, por defecto, todos los `case` están dentro del mismo ámbito. Para evitar que esta estructura te de problemas intenta simplificarla al máximo, y eso implica **no declarar variables entre el `switch` y el primer `case`:

```
switch(valor){
    char Numero_Izq;
    case 0:
```

Dado que esa variable es común a todo el `switch`, declárala antes del propio `switch`:

```
char Numero_Izq;

switch(valor){
    case 0:
```

**Anidar condiciones**

```
if(valor >= 1000){
if(valor <= 9999){
```

Dado que tu función requiere que estos dos `if` se cumplan a la vez, los mismos pueden anidarse facilmente usando expresiones lógicas:

```
if(valor >= 1000 && (valor <= 9999)
```

Con esto consigues reducir el número de condicionales, lo que a la larga mejora la legibilidad del código

**Evita el código replicado**

En ocasiones no hay más remedio que duplicar código, pero la mayoría de las veces se puede evitar. Tienes un ejemplo perfecto en el `switch` ese gigantesco de `Letras_Izquierda`. Si te das cuenta de que un `char` no es más que un número la función se puede simplificar enormemente:

```
int Letras_Izquierda(int valor)
{
    char toReturn;
    if( valor < 26 )
        toReturn = static_cast<char>('a' + valor);
    else
        toReturn = static_cast<char>('A' + valor - 26);

    return toReturn;
}
```

La lógica es sencilla. Si miramos la [tabla ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) podemos ver que los caracteres asociados a las letras están colocados en orden. Empiezan con las mayúsculas seguidos de las minúculas. Eso sí, cada secuencia empieza por la *a*, seguida de la *b* y así hasta la *z*. Si nos lo imaginamos en forma de vector tenemos:

```
indice: 0 1 2 3 4 5
letra:  a b c d e f
```

Así pues vamos a tomar `valor` como si fuese el índice. Así `'a' + valor` nos permitirá movernos por todas las letras minúculas... siempre y cuando `valor < 26`. Con las mayúsculas seguimos la misma lógica. Simplemente hay que restar `26` a `valor` para que esta variable se mueva en el rango `0..25`

**Evita el código replicado (2)**

```
int Primer_Par(int valor){
        if(valor >= 1000){
        if(valor <= 9999){
            char PRIMER_PAR, SEGUNDO_PAR;
            PRIMER_PAR = valor/100;
            SEGUNDO_PAR = valor%100;
            return PRIMER_PAR;
        }
    }
}

int Segundo_Par(int valor){
        if(valor >= 1000){
        if(valor <= 9999){
            char PRIMER_PAR, SEGUNDO_PAR;
            PRIMER_PAR = valor/100;
            SEGUNDO_PAR = valor%100;
            return SEGUNDO_PAR;
        }
    }
}
```

Estas dos funciones solo se diferencian en el valor final que retornan... ¿Por qué tanto código duplicado? En el primer caso no hace falta calcular el resto, y en la primera sobra la división. Además... ¿Qué devuelven estas funciones si, por ejemplo `valor==10`? no hay `return` para los `else`... piénsalo.

En C++ hay una clase que se llama `pair` y, a partir de C++11 su generalización, `tuple`. Estas clases se pueden usar para que una función devuelva varios valores de una sola vez:

```
std::pair<int, int> DividirNumero(int valor)
{
  int primerPar = valor / 100;
  int segundoPar = valor % 100;

  return std::make_pair(primerPar, segundoPar);
}

int valorXIzqPrimerPar, valorXIzqSegundoPar;
std::tie(valorXIzqPrimerPar, valorXIzqSegundoPar) = DividirNumero(CORD_X_IZQ);
```

La función `std::tie` permite extraer facilmente los valores de un `pair` o un `tuple`.

Fíjate además que no me he preocupado de si `valor` está dentro del rango `1000..9999`. Esa validación no debería ser responsabilidad de la función sino de la captura de datos... Si el usuario introduce datos incorrectos habría que avisarle en ese mismo momento y no media hora más tarde... de hecho teóricamente ya has validado el rango de las variables, ¿no? Es lo que se desprende de estas dos líneas:

```
Validar_Negativo(CORD_X_IZQ);
Validate_Size(CORD_X_IZQ);
```

No tiene sentido validar varias veces lo mismo...

Y bueno, hay más cosillas pero tienes trabajo por delante. No desistas.

Comment: Eferion, la variable global la coloqué por el hecho de que todos los resultados se tienen que imprimir al final de todo el código, por lo que lo primero que pensé(siendo novato) fue en variables globales.

Comment: @RoderickGuacuto eso lo piensas porque es de lo primero que te enseñan... pero hay alternativas más sanas :)